# why dots are duplicated in Magento2 PageBuilder Carousel?

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, alpine.js

I'm working on Hyva Theme, with tailwind and Alpine. I've got this problem with carousel dots from PageBuilder, they are doubled and I don't know why.

the file that cares about the PageBuilder carousels is this one
`Magento_PageBuilder::widgets/carousel.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/** @var Template $block */
/** @var Escaper $escaper */

$gliderUrl = $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_PageBuilder::js/glider.min.js');
?>
<script>
    'use strict';

    (() => {
        const initCarousels = (elements) => {
            if (!Glider) {
                return;
            }

            const initProductCarousel = (carousel) => {
                const gliderElement = carousel.querySelector('[data-role="glider-content"]');

                if (!gliderElement) {
                    return;
                }

                const gliderDots = carousel.querySelector('.glider-dots');
                const gliderPrev = carousel.querySelector('.glider-prev');
                const gliderNext = carousel.querySelector('.glider-next');

                const glider = new Glider(gliderElement, {
                    slidesToShow: 6,
                    slidesToScroll: 6,
                    scrollLock: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    dragVelocity: 2.5,
                    dots: gliderDots,
                    arrows: {
                        prev: gliderPrev,
                        next: gliderNext,
                    },
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 0,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1.5,
                                slidesToScroll: 1.5,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1024,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 6,
                                slidesToScroll: 6,
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                });

                carousel.classList.remove('overflow-x-scroll');
                gliderPrev.classList.remove('hidden');
                gliderNext.classList.remove('hidden');

                if (carousel.dataset.autoplay !== 'false') {
                    gliderAutoplay(
                        glider,
                        carousel.dataset.autoplaySpeed,
                        carousel.dataset.infiniteLoop
                    );
                }
            };

            const initSliderCarousel = (slider) => {
                slider.innerHTML = `<div data-role="glider-content">${slider.innerHTML}</div>`;
                slider.classList.add('glider-contain');

                slider.insertAdjacentHTML(
                    'beforeend',
                    '<?= $escaper->escapeJs($block->getBlockHtml('pagebuilder.carousel.nav')) ?>'
                );

                const gliderElement = slider.querySelector('[data-role="glider-content"]');
                const gliderDots = slider.querySelector('.glider-dots');
                const gliderPrev = slider.querySelector('.glider-prev');
                const gliderNext = slider.querySelector('.glider-next');

                const glider = new Glider(gliderElement, {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    scrollLock: true,
                    scrollLockDelay: 250,
                    draggable: true,
                    dragVelocity: 2.5,
                    dots: gliderDots,
                    arrows: {
                        prev: gliderPrev,
                        next: gliderNext,
                    },
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 768,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1024,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1,
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                });

                slider.classList.add('glider-initialized');
                if (slider.dataset.showArrows === 'true') {
                    gliderPrev.classList.remove('hidden');
                    gliderNext.classList.remove('hidden');
                }

                if (slider.dataset.autoplay !== 'false') {
                    gliderAutoplay(
                        glider,
                        slider.dataset.autoplaySpeed,
                        slider.dataset.infiniteLoop
                    );
                }
            };

            const gliderAutoplay = (glider, milliseconds, loop) => {
                const pagesCount = glider.track.childElementCount;
                let slideTimeout = null;
                let nextIndex = 1;
                let paused = false;

                const slide = () => {
                    slideTimeout = setTimeout(
                        () => {
                            if (loop && nextIndex >= pagesCount) {
                                nextIndex = 0;
                            }
                            glider.scrollItem(nextIndex);
                        },
                        parseInt(milliseconds)
                    );
                };

                glider.ele.addEventListener('glider-animated', () => {
                    nextIndex = glider.slide + glider.opt.slidesToScroll;
                    window.clearInterval(slideTimeout);
                    if (!paused && (loop || nextIndex < pagesCount)) {
                        slide();
                    }
                });

                const pause = () => {
                    if (!paused) {
                        clearInterval(slideTimeout);
                        paused = true;
                    }
                };

                const unpause = () => {
                    if (paused) {
                        slide();
                        paused = false;
                    }
                };

                glider.ele.parentElement.addEventListener('mouseover', pause, {passive: true});
                glider.ele.parentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', pause, {passive: true});
                glider.ele.parentElement.addEventListener('mouseout', unpause, {passive: true});
                glider.ele.parentElement.addEventListener('touchend', unpause, {passive: true});

                slide();
            };

            elements.forEach(element => {
                if (element.dataset.contentType === 'products') {
                    initProductCarousel(element);
                }
                if (element.dataset.contentType === 'slider') {
                    initSliderCarousel(element);
                }
            });
        };

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const carouselElements = document.querySelectorAll(
                `[data-content-type="products"][data-appearance="carousel"],
                [data-content-type="slider"]`
            );

            if (carouselElements.length > 0) {
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';

                script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    initCarousels(carouselElements);
                });

                script.src = '<?= $escaper->escapeJs($escaper->escapeUrl($gliderUrl)) ?>';
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

and this is the file where the dots are `Magento_PageBuilder::carousel-nav.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\HeroiconsOutline;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

/** @var Template $block */
/** @var Escaper $escaper */
/** @var ViewModelRegistry $viewModels */

/** @var HeroiconsOutline $heroicons */
$heroicons = $viewModels->require(HeroiconsOutline::class);
?>

<div class="w-full z-10 hidden lg:flex items-center justify-between absolute bottom-1/2 translate-y-1/2 left-0">
    <button
        aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Previous')) ?>"
        class="glider-prev outline-none focus:outline-none">
        <?= $heroicons->chevronLeftHtml('w-10 h-10'); ?>
    </button>

    <button
        aria-label="<?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Next')) ?>"
        class="glider-next outline-none focus:outline-none">
        <?= $heroicons->chevronRightHtml('w-10 h-10'); ?>
    </button>
</div>

<div role="tablist" class="glider-dots lg:hidden select-none flex flex-wrap mx-1 justify-center p-0 focus:outline-none"></div>
```

in the end this is the file that include everything `Magento_PageBuilder::catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\ProductListItem;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\ProductPage;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface;

/** @var ListProduct $block */
/** @var ViewModelRegistry $viewModels */

$productViewModel    = $viewModels->require(ProductPage::class);
$productListItemViewModel = $viewModels->require(ProductListItem::class);

?>
<?php if ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <?php
    $type = 'widget-product-carousel';
    $mode = 'grid';
    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
    $templateType = ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    $description = false;
    ?>
    <div  class="glider-contain custom-carousel product-items <?= /* @noEscape */ $type ?>">
        <div data-role="glider-content" class="mx-auto flex overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-scroll">
            <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
                <?= $productListItemViewModel->getItemHtml($item, $block, $mode, $templateType, $image, $description) ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('pagebuilder.carousel.nav') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Why the dots are practically doubled? it seems they are calculated based on the number of products in the carousel, so there's an error in this calculation?